# Importing Bootstrap into my SCSS via @use instead of @import causes problems

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

My project extends Bootstrap's responsive breakpoints. Here is the entrypoint SCSS file that was working for me:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";

$magnetar-grid-breakpoints : (
    1440: 1440px,
    1600: 1600px,
    1920: 1920px,
    2560: 2560px
);
$grid-breakpoints : map-merge($grid-breakpoints, $magnetar-grid-breakpoints);

$magnetar-container-max-widths : ();

@each $key, $val in $magnetar-grid-breakpoints {
    $magnetar-container-max-widths : map-merge($magnetar-container-max-widths, ($key : 0.95 * $val));
}

$container-max-widths : map-merge($container-max-widths, $magnetar-container-max-widths);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I'm just getting started on this project, and already I can tell that having to prefix all my variables (and mixins and functions) with "magnetar-" in order not to have conflicts with Bootstrap will get old fast. Therefore I thought I'd give the new Sass modules system a try and use `@use` instead of `@import`. Here is the rewritten SCSS:

```
@use "~bootstrap/scss/functions" as bootstrap_func;
@use "~bootstrap/scss/variables" as bootstrap_var;
@use "sass:map";

$grid-breakpoints : (
    1440: 1440px,
    1600: 1600px,
    1920: 1920px,
    2560: 2560px
);
bootstrap_var.$grid-breakpoints : map.merge(bootstrap_var.$grid-breakpoints, $grid-breakpoints);

$container-max-widths : ();

@each $key, $val in $grid-breakpoints {
    $container-max-widths : map.merge($container-max-widths, ($key : 0.95 * $val));
}

bootstrap_var.$container-max-widths : map.merge(bootstrap_var.$container-max-widths, $container-max-widths);

@use "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But the above compiles with this error:

```
SassError: @use rules must be written before any other rules.
```

It's referring to the last line. So I thought I'd try changing that line back to `@import`. That resulted in this error:

```
SassError: $color: theme-color("primary") is not a color.
    ╷
174 │ $link-hover-color:                        darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
    │                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_variables.scss 174:43  @use
```

I'm lost as to what this means. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here is the blog post](https://sass-lang.com/blog/the-module-system-is-launched#use-the-heart-of-the-module-system) about the new SASS module system. This mentions the following:

> In addition to namespacing, there are a few important differences between @use and @import:
>
> - @use only executes a stylesheet and includes its CSS once, no matter how many times that stylesheet is used.
> - **@use only makes names available in the current stylesheet, as opposed to globally.**
> - Members whose names begin with - or _ are private to the current stylesheet with @use.
> - If a stylesheet includes @extend, that extension is only applied to stylesheets it imports, not stylesheets that import it.

The **bold** statement is why it doesn't work with the `@use` directive.
All imported functions are not available globally, meaning the file `~bootstrap/scss/variables` does not know about the functions declared in `~bootstrap/scss/functions`.

I honestly have no idea how to fix this though...

Comment: That's what I figured. The only "fix" is to wait for Bootstrap to be rewritten with @use.

Comment: the link actually is invalid

Comment: So should we go back to using @import?

Answer (score 5):

Just to elaborate on the accepted answer, Bootstrap team argues that they can't migrate to @use because most compilers are yet to support it (even though Sass team doesn't recommend @import any more).

> In short: we can't switch to the new Sass module system yet because
> the majority of build systems doesn't support @use or @foward yet.
>
> One day we will probably switch though (probably in v6).

[Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30025#issuecomment-574825600).

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an error because you are using other statements before your final @use statement - namely the statements to override the values for $grid-breakpoints and $container-max-widths.

> With the @use rule **you need to use the "with" keyword to override
>   those imported values**, rather than defining your overrides first and
>   then using @use.

Since you are importing the entire Bootstrap scss anyways there is no need to separately import the _vars and _functions. 
Just use the statement:

```
@use "yourpath/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" with ( <your overrides here>)
```

I am not sure how you would use an iterator inside that "with"-statement.

A working solution for what you are doing would look like this (sorry, I don't have an iterating solution, just literal assignments):

```
    @use "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" with (
  $grid-breakpoints:(
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  1440: 1440px,
  1600: 1600px,
  1920: 1920px,
  2560: 2560px
  ),
  $container-max-widths :(
    sm: 540px * 0.95,
    md: 720px * 0.95 ,
    lg: 960px * 0.95,
    xl: 1140px * 0.95,
    1440: 1280px,
    1600: 1480px,
    1920: 1800px,
    2560: 2300px
  )
);
```

**Tipp**: Without the "as" keyword the namespace will automatically be the last bit bit of your path i.e."bootstrap" (and there is no scope problem for _variables to know _functions and vice versa as was suggested in another comment).

Please find documentation for all this on the sass-lang.com website:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

Answer (score 1):

You can use [meta.load-css](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta/#load-css) for that:

```scss
@use 'sass:meta' as meta; // add this

// ...
// your code as above

$bootstrap-settings: (
  // variables override - see the docs for more info
);

@include meta.load-css('~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap', $with: $bootstrap-settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
@use '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap' as bs;

.container {
   @include bs.border-radius(1rem);
}
```